# How to get multi-column `\Block` command from `nicematrix` to work with enumerations?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, nicematrix

I am trying to get the enumerations in my table to extend across 3 columns (the bold formatting of row 2 will automatically be removed which is what is desired). It may not seem necessary to include four columns. However, the contents below are just sample for what I actually want to work on

[image]

My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe, margin=11mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*., parsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}l >{\bfseries}X[l, t] X[c, t] X[r, t]}[cell-space-limits=1.1961pt,
                    rules/color=black, rules/width=0.11mm
                   ]

    \Block[tikz={draw=OrangeRed1, thick, rounded corners}]{1-4}<\large\bfseries>{Module 1: Mathematical Background \bigstrut[t]} & & &
    \\
    
    Week 1 & Laplace Transform & &
    \\
    \addlinespace[1mm]
        
    & \Block[l]{1-1}{
        
        \begin{enumerate}
        
            \item Definition of Laplace transform

            \item Laplace transform pairs
            
            \item Useful theorems of Laplace transform
            
            \item Partial fraction expansion
            
            \item Solution of differential equations using Laplace transform
            
        \end{enumerate}

                }
    \\
    
\end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no direct way to do that with `nicematrix`. You have to insert your `{enumerate}` in a `{minipage}` with a width adjusted by hand, itself inserted in the command `\Block`.